# What is a good practice to handle a lot of checkboxes in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I need to build a View which has a 4 layer nested Multi-Accordion with a lot of checkboxes inside them. All together there might be around 30-40 Checkboxes all through the Accordions.

The next step will be, that i have some sort of logic behind all this. Depending on the selection combination of the checkboxes I will change a text label accordingly.

My thought process was: I put up all these checkboxes and give them a numeric fx:id representing there position in the nested accordion graph. Something like "1_1" or "2_4_1".
After that, I build one ChangeListener calling a Method on Selection of a Checkbox. I can look up the Id of the checked box, look it up in my data (to see which Text belongs to it and if any rules interfer with other boxes) and handle the logic accordingly while putting the id and its text in a Map or List to keep it for later and to keep track of the checked boxes.

Now I came to know, that getting the fx:id isnt something JavaFX wants me to do. I cant deliver a custom id in custom property inside the FXML either (couldnt find anything regarding this).
I am now pretty much at the end of my knowledge (I did just start with JavaFX and have some basic Java knowledge) and it seems to me, that I tackle this topic from the wrong side.

My question is now: What would be a best practice to handle dozens of checkboxes and trigger logic in the code according to the box that was checked without writing a ChangeListener for every single Check Box leaving me with some (imo) ugly code all the way.

EDIT: I forgot to mention: I did achieve some sort of functional solution by writing a custom CheckboxChangeListener with a reference to the Element the addListener method was called on and using "getId()" on this reference. I came to know though, that this method references the css:id of the fxml element and not its fx:id and I am not quite sure if this is a proper way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into databinding with javafx. For example:

```
    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("1");
    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("2");

    BooleanProperty isCb1Selected = cb1.selectedProperty();
    BooleanProperty isCb2Selected = cb2.selectedProperty();

    Textfield foo = new TextField().visibleProperty().bind(isCb1Selected.and(isCb2Selected));
```

This would hide the textfield foo if atleast one of the checkboxes isn't selected.
You can find other examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/CreatenconditionalbindingwithWhen.htm) and [here an oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the ressources. I will have a look into it. I was hoping I could work with some sort of identifier (which was the reson behind all this fx:id stuff) because the logic is based on some data inside a database I need to look up. Because of that I need to identify the checkboxes individualy.

Do you think doing this via the "text" of the checkbox is a bad practice? I could replace the ID in the format of "1_1" and so on with the actual text of the Checkbox and check it via "getText()", right?

Comment: Putting the ID as text would be bad practice, but as long as it works and the user doesn't get irritated why not? But I don't understand why you need it. Lets say you give a checkbox the fx:id of `cb1_1` then you can inject it into you controller by `@FXML Checkbox cb1_1` and use the binding I showed you for the conditions (So you don't need to the first two lines of my example).

Comment: Ah! Now I understood what you meant! That is actually the way I am doing it right now. To look up the logic rules of the checkbox I use getId() on the Checkbox, resulting in "cb1_1" and check this against the database to get the logic behind it. I just was not sure if this is the way to go, because as I know using "getId()" should not be used for this purpose. I wasnt sure though and wanted to check my thought process.